# Audit when installed packages were last used

Tags: apt, package-management, docker

I am trying to audit package bloat in my Ubuntu container infrastructure which operates as follows:

1. Base container links in all dependencies. This is done to ensure versions of dependencies are locked to a specific version in one place in order to facilitate package version audits.
2. Other containers inherit from the base container (installing no packages) and run their code.

This system was created a while ago and we have since started to experience some bloat in the containers inheriting from the base container due to unused packages. I am trying to find a way to programatically audit existing container's packages installed via apt-get to see if and when they were last used to help remove some bloat, but have been coming up short on solutions.